# How to support multiple API in drawable?

Tags: android, api, drawable

So I've got a **drawable** directory (sometimes using API level 21 stuff). Trying to support API level 19, I've created a **drawable-v19**, but it doesn't seem to be working as the code from **drawable** (instead of **drawable-v19**) is used.

How do i go about supporting multiple API levels with API dependent code/xml in the drawable directory?

any and all help appriciated.

ps: ive created a layout-v19 directory and setup the AVD to use api level 19 and everything seems to working fine.. except for the drawable problem describe above.

kenneth

Comment: Now I would know why would you try to show different layouts depending on the API, but why would you need different drawables?

Comment: ive got a floating action button xml using the ripple effect in the drawable directory and this breaks api 19 compatability. ive removed all references to this drawable in the layout-v19 directory (in stead using an alternate way to create the ripple effect),  but it is obviously not enough. During the build procedure an error is generated because of the floating action button xml.    should the fab xml file be in the layout directory instead ?

Comment: can you please post the error?